# Backbone.js and PhoneGap, single or multi page?

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js

What I'm trying to do is build a simple app in PhoneGap and Backbone.js.  The app has a login page which, on a successful login, sends the user to a simple menu with a few options. The user has the option to view their saved lists, view a list of items or view an info page.  I know how I want to structure all of the Views and Models so the question I have is whether or not doing this all on one page has any downsides when compared to using multiple pages.

To break it down into smaller parts:

1. Does loading all the javascript in the one page have serious performance implications?
2. If the router closes, .remove() and .unbind(), all the current view when switching to a new view, do I still risk memory issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backbone was designed to be built for SPA applications. Im not saying that you can't span Backbone over multiple pages, but in my opinion that adds more complexity. From your description, I would keep your application as an SPA.

Secondly, build your application using modules. Use a library such as require.js. I could not recommend it enough. I wont go into too much detail about why you should use it, because you can read more about it [here](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#advanced) (I would recommend reading the entire book). Once your application is ready for deployment, you can use r.js, require.js's build script. This will concatenate all or some of your modules into a single file. This will drastically speed up the performance of your app especially if you have a bunch of modules.

Finally with regards to memory optimization, I use a method developed by Derick Bailey which you can read up about [here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: he said it's a simple app, not enough reason to use require.js

Comment: Well I think your opinion is quite subjective. Since  Jdeer is concerned about performance, require.js makes it extremely simple to concatenate his "various pages" into a single file. I can tell you from experience, going the module route reaps many more benefits than it does hindrances, especially if you plan to grow your app. I don't think your opinion warrants a downvote. If you believe my answer to be wrong, by all means provide another solution.

Comment: the performance issue we discussing on this topic is regarding requests and responses, and not with initial content loading. Since the app is a simple app, there wouldn't be such a need to have several pages for templating, and the number of scripts is minimal. You can use something doesn't mean that you have to use it. I didn't say your answer is wrong, I am just saying the part where you mention require.js is wrong. And it will mislead people the way that you got misled.